# WordPress Events Manager Conflict with CiviCRM Registration Pages

Tags: wordpress, civievent, online-registration

I have WordPress 5 running CiviCRM.

We have CiviEvent and CiviContribute enabled and the live registration/donation links are working as expected.

We recently enabled WP Events Manager plugin as well to accommodate some more complex event registrations.

When enabled, the online registration/donation pages redirect to the default CiviCRM page (the one that says Do Not Delete) and the registration/contribution forms disappear.

There are no errors and nothing seems to be wrong other than the fact that the forms no longer display. It doesn't seem to be a URL conflict as the paths are completely different between plugins.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Where would I even begin this debugging issue?

Comment: Try clearing CiviCRM cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The problem is with Events Manager, which overrides permalinks.

I resolved by setting the permalinks to add a leading '/'.

For example:

'events/'
'/events/'